# Different meanings for phrase "off the regular price"

Tags: meaning, expressions

What is the correct way to say a product can be bought with a discount of 30%?

Is it: “Buy this by 30% off the regular price.”?

What I want to say is that a 30% discount is being given, so the product will cost 70% of the regular price.

There seems to be a difference between *of* and *off*. Will this wording be misunderstood to mean that the product can be bought by 30% of the regular price instead of 30% “off” the regular price?

How do I say it correctly and without creating doubt?

Comment: Are you marking a price tag, or printing an advertisement? What is the context?  An ad in the paper might say, "*Everything in the store is* **30% off** *now through Sunday*"

Comment: [I don't think using "x% off" would create any doubt.](https://www.google.com/search?q=off+clotches&sugexp=chrome,mod%3D19&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=W8XpUJ-mCIn5igK3lYGgDw&biw=1361&bih=672&sei=XMXpUOyHJOO1igL7-YGgCQ#um=1&hl=en&newwindow=1&safe=strict&tbo=d&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=+percent+off+&oq=+percent+off+&gs_l=img.3..0i5l7j0i24l3.32037.32869.6.33133.7.7.0.0.0.3.212.685.2j4j1.7.0...0.0...1c.1.ME0IUUFYyXg&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.cGE&fp=7ffcf84e559e008b&bpcl=40096503&biw=1361&bih=672)

Comment: Also, since you buy things *for* a price, the usage here would be:  "*Buy this* **for** *30% off the regular price.*"

Comment: @Jim - I am doing an advertisement.

Comment: As far as I can see, native speakers will not confuse "30% off" and "30% of" ... However a typesetter might make that mistake, producing a misleading ad... "Today only, 30% of the regular price!"

Comment: *Discounted by 30%...* is often used to represent what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

30% off regular price = An item for £100 now costs £70

30% of regular price = An item for £100 now costs £30

You could avoid typesetting errors, as mentioned by GEdgar, by omitting 'regular price'. Any native speaker will understand what '30% off' means.

'30% of' doesn't mean anything on its own.