# What is a product's normal price called?

Tags: single-word-requests

Say a product is normally priced at $14.99, but at various times it goes on sale. Regardless of it's price at any given time, what would the $14.99 price be called?

In other words, I'm looking for the opposite of the sales price.

Answer (score 1):

> Regular price

is the most common phrase used in English.

(31 million hits on google for "regular price")

**Edit:** there's a [related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96952/different-meanings-for-phrase-off-the-regular-price), answered here you might like!

Comment: In Britain a better term might be *usual price*. *Regular* always suggests to me the incidence of bowel movements. Actually most shops label such products in sales as  *£9.99, was £14.99* - though whether you believe them is up to you! (They are expected to conform to trading standards in the way they do this - but I'm sure there is still room for exaggeration).